# bind attribute in custom event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, mustache, sugarcrm

In Sugarcrm (backbone.js) I am trying to get custom  attribute (user_id) from List (in .hbs file)

```
  <div class='dropdown usersLegend'>
            <ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul>
        </div>
```

and bind data dynamically like

```
    _.each(data.users, function (user) {
    list += '<li user_id="' + user.id + '"> ... </li>';
    });
   
     this.$('.usersLegend ul').html(list);
```

I made custom event in initialize

```
  this.events = {
        'click li': 'getselectedUser',
        };
```

and in method, i tried the following code

```
    let currentTarget = JSON.stringify(e.currentTarget);
    if (currentTarget != null) {

    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(currentTarget, "text/xml");
    var tmpDiv = doc.createElement('div');
    tmpDiv.innerHTML = currentTarget;

    var links = tmpDiv.getElementsByTagName('li');
    [...links].forEach((link) => {
    console.log(link.getAttribute('user_id'));
    });


    }
```

this way I am not getting user_id value, how can i bind user_id in custom event

Comment: Welcome to Backbone. I took over maintenance of it.

Answer (score 1):

The `.hbs` extension refers to [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com), which is a template language. This means that you can insert the user IDs right in the `.hbs` file:

```
<div class='dropdown usersLegend'>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        {{#users}}
        <li data-user-id="{{{id}}}"> ... </li>
        {{/users}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

... without having to write the `_.each` loop, *if* you write the `render` method of your view as follows:

```js
this.$el.html(this.template(data));
return this;
```

How this works:

1. The `data` object that contains the `users` array is passed to the compiled template.
2. The compiled template iterates the `users` array inside the `{{#users}}...{{/users}}`. (This is a notation that Handlebars inherited from [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io) (more up-to-date language reference [here](https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/mustache.5.html)). You could also use the notation `{{#each users}}...{{/each}}`, which is specific to Handlebars.)
3. For each user object, the template writes a `<li>` tag with the user ID inserted in an attribute. Note that I use `data-user-id` rather than `user_id` as the attribute name; the `data−` prefix has a special meaning to the browser and to jQuery, so this notation is more likely to work. The `{{{id}}}` notation means "take the `id` attribute of the current object (which is the current user) and interpolate it in the template output without escaping" (`{{id}}` would do the same thing but with escaping).
4. The template returns the generated HTML as a string, which becomes the live HTML of your view through `this.$el.html()`. I presume this last part is currently already happening in your code.

Now, what remains is to take out the user ID after the `'click'` event. For this, `event.target` (not `event.currentTarget`) and jQuery's `.data` method are your friends:

```js
var clickedItem = $(event.target);
var userId = clickedItem.data('user-id');
// Do whatever you need with the user ID...
console.debug(userId);
```